# How bad an idea is intentionally using short RSA keys for signing CloudFront private-content URLs?

Tags: rsa, key-generation

While pondering a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31376763/how-to-cope-with-the-performance-of-generating-signed-urls-for-accessing-private/31551075#31551075) on SO about efficiently generating [signed private-content URLs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-signed-urls.html) for CloudFront I decided to check what sorts of savings could be found by using a shorter RSA key. With the 2048-bit key AWS generates, our signing method runs in around ~1550µs on my laptop; using a 512-bit key cuts this down to ~113µs.

We sign the links to grant paid users access to media files for a given number of minutes, and have already been using the equivalent SHA-1 HMAC signing process for gating access to the same files on S3. The vast majority of the requests our server fills are for these signed URLs.

How acceptable/unacceptable is it to use a short length for a key dedicated to this purpose? What qualifies as acceptably long/short?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Right now** (July 2015), the current record for RSA key breaking is for a [768-bit modulus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_numbers#RSA-768), and it took two years of computations with a lot of machines, and, importantly, with some very fine brains too. A notable point is that the best known RSA-breaking method (that was used for RSA-768) is integer factorization with the [General Number Field Sieve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_number_field_sieve); GNFS does *not* benefit from any kind of "precomputation". This means that the people who factored the 768-bit RSA key, if faced with another 768-bit RSA key to break, would *again* have to spend two years on the job.

As for 1024-bit RSA keys:

- they are currently unbroken;
- they *could* be broken with existing technology, but it would require throwing at the problem a non-negligible number of millions of dollars to build a dedicated machine that would be good *only* at breaking 1024-bit RSA;
- ... and even that machine, if it is ever built, would still need a lot of time (months, possibly years) to break a RSA key.

In your case, if signatures only need to resist for a few minutes, then you could *generate* a new RSA key every day, and this will defeat GNFS-based attackers as long as breaking a 1024-bit RSA key takes more than a day, a property which is quite likely to hold for the next few decades. A good point (for you) is that since your signatures become obsolete quickly, you "just" have to keep track of scientific and technological advances: the day some people succeed at breaking a 1024-bit RSA key, you can switch to 2048-bit keys; you do not have to do it in advance.

Comment: Thank you for giving both a lucid answer to the immediate question and enough insight into your reasoning that it should be easy to apply even as the specifics change.

Comment: The only caveat to that is a patient attacker that is logging all traffic on the network. They could then use the keys to decrypt the traffic even years later, so those paid-content media files could be decrypted after enough time. If that's a problem, then a higher-strength encryption level would be better.

Comment: @AaronD The media files themselves are not encrypted (HTML5 video, etc.) The generated signature is just used by CloudFront to verify that the time-limited URL used was both generated by us, and hasn't been tampered with.

Comment: @AaronD: that's the point: we are not talking about _encryption_ but _signatures_. If a new key is generated every day, then it does not matter if an attacker breaks a key that was used two years before -- it won't be accepted anyway. This highlights that encryption and signatures use really distinct security models.